# achartengine bargraph values

Tags: android, achartengine

I display (stacked) bargraphs fine. No issues.

However I normalize data to be within a 0-100% range, but would like on some bars to display the non-normalized data (at the top of the rendered graph).

How can I display any value I choose to be displayed at the tip/top of each graph?

I did look at the achartengine Javadoc but can't see a method for this, perhaps I missed it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new type of `BarChart` rendering called `HEAP` that probably does what you need. You can download a version including this feature [here](https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.2.0/).

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting you right, U should use this to display chart values.

```
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
 renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
```